# how to write lengthy string in memory mapped file?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have list of data in object list like below:

```
price:10, volumne:100, timestamp:1253568545
price:8, volumne:15, timestamp:4564546584545
price:68, volumne:846, timestamp:3548432545
```

so now I want to write this data into memory mapped file same as I have write here. Like every new symbol information in new line. So how to do it? I have mentioned my code below so please help me to solve this.

````
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"D:\data.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "map1", 1000))
{
   using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
   {
     foreach (var item in data.ticks)
     {
       byte[] data1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.t.ToString() + "," + item.p.ToString() + "," + item.s.ToString());
       accessor.WriteArray(0, data1, 0, data1.Length);
      }
    }
}```

In final I need a result like below so please help for solve it:
10,100,1253568545
8,15,4564546584545
68,846,3548432545
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.WriteArray()` method first argument is the relative position within the view where it has to start writing. Whenever you have written something you have to increase that cursor accordingly to the written bytes. And if the bytes to write plus the current position exceeds the current window size, you have to create a new view on the desired position. Here is an example:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 80).Select(i => new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = $"Item {i}" }).ToList();

using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"D:\data.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "myMap", 4096))
{
    MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = null;
    // Small window size to enforce roll-over for testing.
    var windowSize = 100;
    var absolutePosition = 0;
    var relativePosition = 0;

    try
    {
        accessor = file.CreateViewAccessor(absolutePosition, windowSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var value = $"{item.Id},{item.Name}{Environment.NewLine}";
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

            if (bytes.Length + relativePosition > windowSize)
            {
                absolutePosition += relativePosition;
                relativePosition = 0;
                accessor.Dispose();
                accessor = file.CreateViewAccessor(absolutePosition, windowSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
            }

            accessor.WriteArray(relativePosition, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            relativePosition += bytes.Length;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (accessor != null)
            accessor.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Oliver. It's working fine. If I am using simple txt file instead of memory mapped file then will it work like memory mapped file. Like if multiple process will use same file at a time then will it cause misbehavior ?

Comment: @hardikdhankecha: I don't fully understand your question. But it is possible that multiple processes write into the same file, cause you can open a file with `FileShare.ReadWrite`. But it is very, very, very hard to synchronize the position at which each process starts and stops to write. Instead I would let every process write into its own file and at the end merge them into one big (if needed).